# MultiFInd Replace Based On Table MakroExcelVBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, replace, substitution

I have the issue with this code below
When I have about more then 80 phrases to replace macro skips some random phrases.
When I isolate this phrase macro was fine.

```
Sub MultiFindNReplace()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Replace Range :", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
        InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you create a [reprex] with sample data where the random phrase gets skipped?

Comment: sure, here it comes https://www.dropbox.com/s/dmttbw0b7olxi4a/Linki.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: The `Original Range` is the range where the replacements will take place. The `Replace Range` is a two-column range where the first column contains the strings to be found and the second column the strings to replace with. Your workbook whose link you have posted in your comment has nothing to do with the mentioned. Consider explaining what is happening in more detail and/or supply a link to the workbook where you actually plan on using the code. You should consider adding more arguments to the `Replace` method, e.g. the `LookAt` and the `MatchCase` arguments have no default parameter.

Comment: it crashes with higher number of text to replace https://www.dropbox.com/s/dmttbw0b7olxi4a/links2.xlsx?dl=0